# background image pixelated

Tags: objective-c, image

I want a background image on my grouped UITableView, so I used the code:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
```

But the image is pixelated. I think I want to change the content mode, but since it is not a UIImageView... I can't seem to do it.

Is there another way to make a background image for a UITableViewController out of a UIImageView?

[image: Here is the correct image]

[image: This is the pixelated image]

Comment: show some tableView code. maybe image is too small?

Comment: the code posted is in ViewDidLoad, what else do you want to see? Image is definitely not too small, but if so... is there a way to tile it?

Comment: image should have tableView dimension. When it's larger or smaller then you have blurry/pixelated background.

Comment: Are you testing on a device with a Retina Display? If so, then you probably need to add a high-res version of the image and tag with with the @2x keyword in your Project Navigator, such as: imageName@2x.png along with the regular imageName.png. (You have to make sure the image is double the resolution of the original image).

Be mindful that you can simply use [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] and the compiler will figure out what version of the png to pull out.

Comment: I am using a 2X image. When I have it in a UIImageView in a UIViewController it works, but when I set it as the background of a UITableViewController it does not. I included screenshots.

Comment: @user1530460 are you using "@2X" or "@2x"? If I remember correctly the filesystem on iOS is case-sensitive but not on OSX...so things can work in the simulator but fail on devices due to filename problems.

Answer (score 0):

I created a project [Patterns](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/Patterns.zip) that you can download and plug your two images into - it correctly grabs the retina image for retina iPhone simulator, and the normal one for normal device. Plug your wood image into it and see if it works. Assuming it does not then something is wrong with your images - post them on dropbox.

If it does work, then there is something you are doing in your project that's not right - you forgot to include the retina image in the target etc.